# How to consume declarations from declaratoinDir in an another project

Tags: typescript

https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/43500

We have several projects some of them written on JavaScript some on TypeScript. To share code between projects we have "common" library written on JavaScript. But for TypeScript projects we want to provide type declarations based on JSDoc compiled to d.ts.

We can easily generate d.ts files based on JSDoc, but we want to keep them in a separate folder (**We don't want to put .d.ts files near js files**). TypeScript provide options for that `declaratoinDir`. Problem how to consume this type declarations in projects which use "common" library?

Structure of shipped "common" library

```
common/foo/foo.js
common/types/foo/foo.d.ts
```

Currently, if import "common/foo/foo" in TypeScript project we get error that we don't have d.ts file for this module

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would say that the best way to enable this is to leverage project references.

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/project-references.html#what-is-a-project-reference

The specific benefits listed on that page include

> - **Importing modules from a referenced project will instead load its output declaration file (`.d.ts`)**